# How to convert URL file 'Smooth streaming' to Apple HLs format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, azure, http-live-streaming

In

- iOS App
- for Live streaming

I am getting the response from server

like this, (You can check)

**http://4a75a0cce3694e29bc670b3d574fec92.cloudapp.net/push.isml/manifest**

**Which is Smooth Streaming file.**

How to play this file in my ios app.

1. Is there any run time converter to convert this file to Apple HLS ?
2. Any player**(Smooth Streaming)** like

   - OSMF plugin for iOS
   - HTML5 player
   - Silverlight plugin for iOS

Actually :

- Actually we have not tried much with Azure Framework. We setted up
  the IIS server  and got the live streaming.
- Played stream by HTML5 video tag in web view.
  By following this link 
  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=86968cd5-feeb-47f2-b02e-1eb4fa556379#commentstart

We can able to play live streaming in our iOS devices.

Still I am happy if I can configure the windows AZure framework to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Windows Azure Media Services for converting SmoothStreaming media content into Apple HLS content. Either you use the [Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/MediaServicesExtension/MediaService) to upload your media assets and then encode it with the preset "Playback on iOS devices and PC/MAC" or you use the REST Api for the Windows Azure Media Services at runtime.

With the REST API you can utilize the Windows Media Packager to encode Smooth Streaming content for HLS. Find a [sample configuration for that task here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973635.aspx).

Comment: 2. While using sample configuration for REST API. Where to write the code ?

Comment: This is definately not to discourage you. We  actually moved by this URL http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=86968cd5-feeb-47f2-b02e-1eb4fa556379#commentstart and we setted up IIS server and through that local server we are getting the stream in our WebView through HTML5(iOS device).

Comment: No offense taken. I'm glad you managed to somehow reach your goal. But now you are relying on an on-premise solution. If you still want to move into the cloud your on-premise experience might be of great help, because Azure Media Services are IIS features with scaling capabilities.
You can use the Task (.xej-file) you used in Expression Encoder to let Azure Media Services do the encoding job and make your stream available over Azure. For managing purposes I would write a simple WPF application that uploads, encodes and publishes your assets.
And yes - both can do live streaming.

Comment: No doubt it is an OnPremise Solution.And we would like to move on Cloud. I am going thriough that and respond  you for sure.